# Why does SQL Server need to have such precise date formats?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I know this may come across as  a newbie question, but I'm curious as to why dates in SQL need to look like this:

```
FieldBeginDate
2010-04-01 00:00:00.000

FieldEndDate
2010-12-31 23:59:00.000
```

Why the three-decimals or precision? And Is there a way to have dates shown as Month-Day-Year only?   thanks!

Comment: I know you already accepted an answer, but you know you can convert the date using the convert command to a format you choose. If you use convert with an nvarchar(10) it automatically knows how to convert it to something that fits that size constraint.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SQL Server 2008 has a `DATE` type, which dismisses the time.

Using the `DATE` type, rather than the `DATETIME` type also takes only a single `int` to store the value... as opposed to the *two* `int`s needed to store a `DATETIME`

**EDIT:** You also ask why there are three decimal places... This is because of the precision with which the value is stored *by default* (@AaronBetrand aptly points out in the comments below that you *can* obtain extended precision). SQL Server stores times in *one-three-hundredths-of-a-second* increments.

Here is SQLDenis on the topic: 
http://blogs.lessthandot.com/index.php/DataMgmt/DataDesign/how-are-dates-stored-in-sql-server

Comment: And also `DATETIME2(7)`, which allows for 7 decimal places instead of just 3. And doesn't have horrible 3ms rounding issues.

Comment: To be precise, a DATE only requires 3 bytes as opposed to 4 for an int.

Comment: @AaronBertrand inteed, but the OP seems to be asking for *less* precision.

Comment: Yes, I'm just complementing with more information. Remember that answers are not just for the OP's benefit alone; a future reader might search for "date precision", look at your answer and think they can only have less precision.

Comment: Thanks so much! I would have never guessed that it was one-three-hundredths of-a-second.

Comment: @AaronBertrand as to your point about the "3 bytes".. you are correct (And you have explored this quite well in another answer) but, if I read your previous answer correctly, it still resolves to an `int` on the page.